# How can I decorate jelly

Tags: gelatin, decorating

This is jelly as in Jello (either gelatine-based or vegetarian), not as in jam.  I'd buy it in the right base colour/flavour.

I appear to have been volunteered to make Shopkins¹-themed food -- at least a cake and as little more as I can get away with.  One thing that looks quite simple is [Wobbles](http://shopkins.wikia.com/wiki/File:Wobbles.png).

This is essentially a green jelly (classic jelly mould shape) with eyes and a mouth.  The eyes themselves could be made from icing quite easily, but how could they be attached? The mouth could do with being outlined in a darker shade of green: piped on? painted with food colouring?

So I'd like to stick icing onto jelly on a near-vertical surface (or find some other way of getting the white) and paint/pipe onto jelly.

---

¹Colourful collectible plastic things with faces, only comprehensible to small children.

Comment: I got out of it in the end, but may have to revisit the plan later this year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for two molds shaped as Wobbles eyes. 
Fill the mold's border and center with black gelatin and leave it in the fridge until it's set. Add white gelatin for the eyeballs. Leave it in the fridge again. When the eyes are set you can put them **inside** the bigger mold and fill it with green gelatine.

This is an example of the same effect using candy fish and blue gelatin.
You could even use candy eyes and save time.

[image]
Jello aqualium.

Comment: That's neat. I could probably improvise an eye mould. I might be inclined to chill the eyes a bit extra to avoid them melting into the green which might cause nightmares. I've actually got some candy eyes but they might be a bit small.

Comment: @ChrisH : actually, you want it not quite fully set, or they won't fuse together.